# Infinispan 5.3.0 - Using UDP protocol for multicasting without cluster configurations and JGroups

Tags: infinispan

We are using Infinispan for caching on Tomcat 7.0. We found that Infinispan making UDP requests for multicasting without JGroups and cluster configuration. We observed Infinispan jar itself contains jgroups-udp.xml. But we are not referring it no where. Is infinispan by default uses UDP protocol for multi/uni casting the messages?
 The cache configuration file we used is here.

```
        <infinispan
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.3 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.3.xsd"
           xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.3">

        <global>
           <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
        </global>

       <namedCache name="FORMS">
            <jmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
            <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="1000" />
            <expiration lifespan="86400000" /><!--  Setting expiration to 1 day -->
       </namedCache>

      </infinispan>
```

Comment: That's weird. For clustering to kick in, a `<transport />` element needs to be within `<global>`, and a clustered cache needs to be defined. Maybe you can share how the cache manager is created?